# analog circuit nodal analysis

Tags: analog, circuit-analysis

I had difficulty in evaluating following circuit's node analysis to find the transfer function. I had difficulty because of the ground in the middle of the circuit and the way the source voltage is attached to circuit. I would be very happy if you can show how i should evaluate the node equations. Thank you very much.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An RC twin T circuit like this will generally have the transfer function: -

[image]

For the circuit below: -

[image]

Even with R1 = R2 etc it's by no means a simple thing you are asking so I would say to you this...

> Here's the answer (above) and it can be simplified to give the desired
>   answer in your question, but where are you getting stuck i.e. how far
>   have you got with solving this?

Comment: thank you for the answer. Im stuck in writing node equation according to input voltage. will it be as following
(Va-Vin)/r1 + Va*2cs+ (Va-V0)/R2=0 for the upper node and 

(Vb-vin9/cs + b/r2 + (vb-vo)/cs= 0 for the one in the below. if it would be like that, shouln't I need another equation to evaluate the transwer function?

Comment: Try looking down the page on this site: http://circuitplay.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/the-twin-t-filter.html - it's not that easy of course.

Comment: Here's another that might be useful: http://www.niu.edu/~mfortner/labelec/lect/p575_07a.pdf

Comment: Also try this one: http://www.millersville.edu/physics/experiments/111/index.php